# To determine the user's role in the project

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

In my django website I have pages like 'project_list' and 'project_detail'. Every project has members with different roles (developer, manager, e.t.c.). I want to show different buttons depending on the current user's role in the project in template. I need ideas how to realise it. Lets say something like that in template:

{% if request.user.role_in_the_current_project = 'manager' %}
   SOW SOMETHING
{% endif %}

**models.py**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250,)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publication_date',)
    *Other fields*

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('project:project_detail', args=[self.slug])

class Membership (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        ('manager', 'Manager'),
        ('developer', 'Developer'),
        ('business_analyst', 'Business analyst'),
        ('system_analysts', 'System analysts'),
    )

    role = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ROLE_CHOICES,)
```

**view.py**

```
def project_detail(request, slug):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, slug=slug, status='public')
    return render(request, 'project/project_detail.html', {'project': project,})
```

**project_detail.html**

```
{% block content %}
   <h1>{{ project.name }}</h1>
   <p>{{ project.description|linebreaks }}</p>
{%endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^project/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', project_detail, name='project_detail'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concept of [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#choices) inside a model field and then by using these you can make decisions inside your templates (or to your views) to show appropriate content.

Let me know if you need more info on this.

[EDIT]: So, what you want is to check each time the value of `role`. Right?

In your `views.py` write:

```
project = get_object_or_404(Project, slug=slug, status='public')
memberships = project.membership_set.all()
```

Then because one project can have many `Membership` records you should iterate over the `memberships` to get each time the `role`.

So, in your template:

```
{% for membership in memberships %}
    {% if membership.role == 'Manager' %} Do stuff here {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Note that `.role` will give you back the second value of the `ROLE_CHOICES` sub-tuple which is capitalized, while the first one is that will be shown in the user if you use the function [`get_role_display()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)

Comment: Well I know it. I need help with realisation. As you see inside model Membership I have role field with choices concept. Now I little bit comfused with project_detail view to take request user`s role in that project.

Comment: I used this in template but it didnt help `{% if request.user.project.membership__role == 'manager' %}<button>Create</button>{% endif %}` Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Just {% if request.user.role = 'Manager' %} didnt work. So sad =(

Comment: '{% for membership in memberships %}' also didnt work. I think we need somehow to say system about request user inside view or not? How do you think?

Comment: Why it didn't work? Please make a `[print(m.role) for m in memberships]` after the line `memberships = project.membership_set.all()`. What do your get?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after all I found solusion. In view I add:

```
is_manager = project.membership_set.filter(user=request.user, role='Manager').exists()
```

Then in template I add:

```
{% if is_manager %}
    <button>Create</button>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out! I was blackout and didn't think clearly. I think I need some sleep. Happy coding!